# Connect to mysql rds using python lambda

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am very new to python code and doing some small tests to verify functionality

Currently trying to establish the connection between an RDS MySQL and a python lambda function.

However, it seems to fail in the code itself and I am not sure why this happens.
There are a couple of guides out there but they all seem to be outdated and fail to work for me.

These are the steps I took to get it working(using MAC-12.3.1 and VS-Studio 1.62.3):

1. created MYSQL RDS
2. connected to the MYSQL RDS and created a database called "igor" with table name "lumigor", with 2 columns: id and name (populated with random data).
3. created on the local machine a folder to contain the code and the package.
4. installed version Python 3.8.9
5. created lambda function file app.py with the following code:

````
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='rds end point',
                            user='user',
                            password='pswrd',
                            database='igor',
                            cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)

with connection:
   with connection.cursor() as cursor:
       # Read a single record
       sql = "SELECT * FROM `Lumigor`"
       cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
       result = cursor.fetchone()
       print(result)
   ```
````

1. I added requirement.txt file with the following command

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL && pip3 freeze > requirements.txt --target...
```

But now I get an error from the visual studio:

"Import "pymysql.cursors" could not be resolved from sourcePylance"

When I zip the file and upload it to lambda, run a test it returns an error

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'pymysql.cursors'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

It seems like the dependcies are missing even though installed them and they exist in the directory

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to add `pymysql` to your lambda is by creating a dedicated layer a as described in the **AWS blog**:

- [How do I create a Lambda layer using a simulated Lambda environment with Docker?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/)

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
PyMySQL
```

3. Run the following docker command (new image from 
   [lambci/docker-lambda](https://github.com/lambci/docker-lambda/issues/349#issuecomment-926645369) for Python 3.9):

```
docker run --rm --volume "$PWD:/var/task" --workdir /var/task senorcoder/aws-lambda-env:python3.9_build pip install -Ur requirements.txt --target python
```

4. Create layer as zip:

```
zip -r mypymysqllayer.zip python > /dev/null
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mypymysqllayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtimes` to `python3.9`.
6. Add the layer to your function:

**Alternatively**, create  your function as [Lambda container image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/images-create.html)

Comment: @IgorKarpenko No problem. Let me know how did it go.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,
I got it to work, thanks for the answer.